# C# Regex to match pattern [word] text (more)

Tags: c#, regex

I need a C# regex that can find a patter in a string.

This is the string:

`[Tommy] wants 'gum' and [Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black') and [money] is not ('char', 'string') and [Mr Smith's [right hand man]] is ('Johny', 'Tommy') and [Mr Smith] sales 'wine'`

What I am looking to pull out is:

`[Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black')
[Mr Smith's [right hand man]] is ('Johny', 'Tommy')`

Anything could be inside of the brackets and there could be an unlimited amount of items between the parentheses.

Comment: Show some research/trying effort?

Comment: Do you mean that the matches should be [...] is (...) ?

Comment: What should we do with 
"[Tommy] wants 'gum' anfds ] dsfds [ dsfdd [Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black')"? 
Is it  "[ dsfdd [Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black')" or 
"[Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black')" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text =
        @"[Tommy] wants 'gum' and [Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black') and [money] is not ('char', 'string') and [Mr Smith's [right hand man]] is ('Johny', 'Tommy') and [Mr Smith] sales 'wine'";
    var pattern = @"((\[[^\]\[]*\])|(\[[^\[\]]*\[[^\[\]]*][^\[\]]*\])) is \(.*?\)";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var matches = regex.Matches(text);
    var listOfMatches = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        listOfMatches.Add(match.Value);
    }
}
```

is working for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
\[[^\[\]]+(\[[^\[\]]+\])?\] is \([^\(\)]+\)
```

> [Tommy] wants 'gum' and **[Johny's last name] is ('Smith', 'Doe', 'Black')** and [money] is not ('char', 'string') and **[Mr Smith's [right hand man]] is ('Johny', 'Tommy')** and [Mr Smith] sales 'wine'